# 'simple' CSS tweaks needed for a responsive menu

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I found a great tutorial on building a clean, responsive menu and it's ALMOST perfect!

Please take a look at www.gymnasticsvillage.com/unifirst/navtest (not in IE as I haven't added response.js yet!) and reduce your browser to the break point (480)

I haven't got a response yet from the blog author and I KNOW this could be simple for a CSS guru...what I need help with is:

1) when you open a subnav, the down arrow graphic should be swapped with an up arrow to cue the user to collapse. I made the graphic 'upArrow.png' just don't know what to do now!

2) right now the menu acts as sliding panels but I would love it more like an accordion, automatically collapsing a submenu when another is selected

I hope somebody can help...thanks so much!

If anybody wants a great tutorial, check it out!
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/big-menus-small-screens-responsive-multi-level-navigation/

Comment: I don't see any sub-navs... not in firefox as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward i think.

This is the css you need for the up arrow.  Add it at the end of the `@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {` section.

```
.nav li.hover > .parent {
    background-image: url('../images/upArrow.png');
}
```

Line 146 of the css file should be this so you don't lose the arrow (`.nav > li > * a:hover`):

```
background-color:#017865;
```

Line 36 of the js file needs to be this:

```
$(this).parent("li").toggleClass("hover").siblings('li').removeClass("hover");
```

Comment: Thanks John! This works perfect for the top level. Is there any way to extend this down to sublevels?

I played around with  .nav * .parent {
    background-image: url('../images/upArrow.png');
} to no avail

Comment: I change the css selector to `.nav li.hover > .parent`.  I believe this should fix your issue.

Comment: I KNEW I was close!  Getting the hang of these child selectors :)

This worked perfectly...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, I'm using Twitter Bootstraps dropdown. If you don't want to use it, maybe you could 'steal' some ideas of how they implement their responsive menu.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a subnav, for the up arrow

```
.nav > li:hover > a {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #D1D2D4;
    background-image: url("../images/upArrow.png");
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I implemented this and it gave me the up arrow on ALL the hovers. I only want the down arrow to swap to the up arrow when a section is 'open'

I don't believe it's a 'hover' I'm looking for...perhaps some sort of 'active' state when a section is expanded?

I hope this clarifies

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
.nav li.hover > a {
    background-image: url("../img/upArrow.png");
}
.nav li li.hover > a {
    background-image: url("../img/upArrow.png");
}
```